# Average value of a function with two variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

How would I determine the average value of a function of two variables over two intervals, both of which have given bounds.

Assume the function `f[x,y]` (below) has bounds `x, y = [0,5]`. I believe the average should be computed by integrating, but I've only done that with a function of one variable.

```
Sqrt[1 + .25y^2 ((2.5 + 1.5 Cos[Pi/3 x] - 2.75)^2 + 
     y^2(2.4 + 1.1 Sin[Pi/3 x] - 3.75)^2)]
```

Comment: `NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]/25`

Answer (score 4):

This is an elaboration of Bob Hanlon's comment.

The average value of a function of two variables over a given domain is the integral of the function divided by the area of the domain.

The calculation goes like so:

Given

```
f[x_, y_] := 
  Sqrt[1 + .25 y^2 ((2.5 + 1.5 Cos[Pi/3 x] - 2.75)^2 + 
       y^2 (2.4 + 1.1 Sin[Pi/3 x] - 3.75)^2)]

domain = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 5}];
```

then

```
integral = Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ domain]
```

> `143.278`

```
average = integral/Area[domain]
```

> `5.73113`

Visualization

```
Show[
  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ domain],
  Graphics3D[
    {Green, Opacity[.5], InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, #}, {1, 0, #}, {0, 1, #}} &[avg]]}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I like that you used the region functionality to get the pedagogical point across.